# How to programmatically set drawableLeft on Android button?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo

I'm dynamically creating buttons.  I styled them using XML first, and I'm trying to take the XML below and make it programattic.

```xml
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonIdDoesntMatter"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="buttonName"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/imageWillChange"
    android:onClick="listener"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
</Button>
```

This is what I have so far.  I can do everything but the drawable.

```java
linear = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearView);
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("Button");
button.setOnClickListener(listener);
button.setLayoutParams(
    new LayoutParams(
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,         
        android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    )
);      

linear.addView(button);
```

Answer (score 1221, accepted):

You can use the `setCompoundDrawables` method to do this. See the example [here](http://mgmblog.com/2010/06/04/setcompounddrawable-to-add-drawables-to-textview/). I used this without using the `setBounds` and it worked. You can try either way.

**UPDATE**: Copying the code here incase the link goes down

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smiley);
img.setBounds(0, 0, 60, 60);
txtVw.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
```

**or**

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.smiley);
txtVw.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(img, null, null, null);
```

**or**

```
txtVw.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: @Varun, @Tigger: I have a problem with this: My filemanager shows folders in a  listview with textviews and a folder icon as a `drawableLeft`. I tried your suggestions here to set a "forbidden icon" when you click in a folder without read permissions, and it works. However, when you change folders and the adapter is reloaded, the forbidden icon persists (that is, `drawableLeft` are not redrawn). Do you know how to apply `notifyDataSetChanged` also for the `drawableLeft`, without doing a loop? Thanks!

Comment: @LuisA.Florit It sounds like you have a question related to the redrawing of a `Listview` item when the data changes - which does not really relate to this question or answer. I suggest you post a question instead of a comment.

Comment: @Tigger: Well, I reverted back the icon using your trick also, and a loop over the forbidden dirs. Maybe this is better than redrawing all the ListView items... Thanks anyway!

Comment: I'm seeing something strange in my app. The `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( 0, 0, R.drawable.money, 0 )` doesn't work, if I define the drawableRight in the layout.xml. If I set the original icon inside `onCreate()`, then the change works. Could it be related to API 19?

Comment: Example link is not opening. Is there any alternative link?

Comment: As described in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18279169/43051), using this code is safer to avoid removing existing drawables:

`Drawable[] drawables = textViewExample.getCompoundDrawables();
textViewExample.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(leftDrawable, drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3]);`

Comment: @Varun Hi sir,How to remove that add image in edittext.

Comment: what about `drawableStart` and `drawableEnd` ?

Comment: Actually must use  -> ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.your_drawable)

Comment: For me `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` worked but `setCompoundDrawables` didn't.

Answer (score 133):

Simply you can try this also

```
txtVw.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: R.drawable.smiley should be in the place of the first 0 (the first parameter) not the last because the definition of this method is: {public void setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)}

Comment: How can I add padding around this, too? There's not much padding between the drawable and the text this way.

Answer (score 40):

## Kotlin Version

Use below snippet to add a drawable left to the button:

```
val drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_16dp)
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)
```

### Important Point in Using Android Vector Drawable

When you are using an **android vector drawable** and want to have backward compatibility for **API below 21**, add the following codes to:

In app level `build.gradle`:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}
```

In Application class:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        
        AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true)
    }

}
```

Comment: A simpler way that also works for me:  button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_favorite_white_16dp), null, null, null)

Comment: You are right, but `Context#.getDrawable(resId)` is deprecated, so using it may cause some problems.

Comment: Works for without adding in Application class since I do not have one.

Answer (score 29):

```
myEdtiText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.smiley, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 24):

For me, it worked:

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(com.example.project1.R.drawable.ic_launcher, 0, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using *drawableStart*, *drawableEnd*, *drawableTop* or *drawableBottom*; you must use "**setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds**"

```
edittext.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.anim_search_to_close, 0)
```

Answer (score 10):

Worked for me. To set drawable at the right

```
tvBioLive.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_close_red_400_24dp, 0)
```

Answer (score 6):

I did this:

```
 // Left, top, right, bottom drawables.
            Drawable[] drawables = button.getCompoundDrawables();
            // get left drawable.
            Drawable leftCompoundDrawable = drawables[0];
            // get new drawable.
            Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            // set image size (don't change the size values)
            img.setBounds(leftCompoundDrawable.getBounds());
            // set new drawable
            button.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 4):

as @Jérémy Reynaud pointing out, as described in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18279169/43051), the safest way to set the left drawable without changing the values of the other drawables (top, right, and bottom) is by using the previous values from the button with [setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable,%20android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)):

```
Drawable leftDrawable = getContext().getResources()
                          .getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable);

// Or use ContextCompat
// Drawable leftDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(),
//                                        R.drawable.yourdrawable);

Drawable[] drawables = button.getCompoundDrawables();
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(leftDrawable,drawables[1],
                                               drawables[2], drawables[3]);
```

So all your previous drawable will be preserved.

Answer (score 4):

Might be helpful:

```
TextView location;
location=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.complain_location);
//in parameter (left,top,right,bottom) any where you wnat to put
location.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.arrow,0);
```

Answer (score 4):

### Add a Kotlin Extension

If you are going to be doing this frequently, adding an extension makes your code more readable. Button extends TextView; use Button if you want to be more narrow.

```
fun TextView.leftDrawable(@DrawableRes id: Int = 0) {
    this.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(id, 0, 0, 0)
}
```

To use the extension, simply call

```
view.leftDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable)
```

Anytime you need to clear, don't pass a param or make another extension called `removeDrawables`

Answer (score 3):

Following is the way to change the color of the left icon in edit text and set it in left side.

```
 Drawable img = getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.user );
img.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );
mNameEditText.setCompoundDrawables(img,null, null, null);

int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.blackColor);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    DrawableCompat.setTint(img, color);

} else {
    img.mutate().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
     fillButton[i].setBackground(getBaseContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.drawable_name));
}
else {
    fillButton[i].setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,193,234,203));
}
```

Answer (score -8):

Try this:

```
((Button)btn).getCompoundDrawables()[0].setAlpha(btn.isEnabled() ? 255 : 100);
```

Comment: myEdtiText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( R.drawable.smiley,0, 0, 0); works