# How do I scale a .JPEG to fit inside a button that rests in a GridView?

Tags: java, android, image, button, gridview

I have a number of `Button`s that are dynamically added to a `GridView` using an `Adapter`. These currently fit inside the GridView correctly, but...

I would like to add an image inside each button. I have `banana.jpg` stored in my `drawable` folder and I use the following code to set it inside the button:

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.banana));
```

However, I have two problems:

1. The buttons seem to stretch to the size of the image.
2. The image doesn't actually appear.

Is there some way to add an image to a button such that the current size of the button will scale the image down so that it fits? (Or, is it possible to calculate the size I will need the image to be so I can resize it manually?)

Comment: @Perception Similar, but I am not sure how to scale - and I would prefer the GridView to do it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `ImageButton` instead of `Button`,

If you want to use `Button` may be [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502650/1773155) can help you.

Comment: I've been using `Button` so I can use text alongside the image.

Comment: and what about the answer on the link?

Comment: I am trying it using: `Drawable icon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.banana);
   button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, null, null, null);` but it doesn't show any image on my buttons when I run the application. It's just a blank button (and the text is now missing).

Comment: Ah there seems to be something wrong with my drawable/Eclipse/.jpg. Your solution works with the built in Android icons. Thanks!