# Programmatically change drawableLeft of Button

Tags: android, image, button, textview, drawable

I'm using a Button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/zoom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/trans"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/left_img"
        android:fontFamily="arial"
        android:text="My Name is "
        android:textSize="50sp" />
```

and changing its text color with :

```
zoom.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("voilet"));
```

but not able to understand **`how to change its image??`**

Comment: take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html#CustomBackground to style your button

Comment: set like this button.setBackground(R.drawable.ic_launcher); inside the onclick listener.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programatically set drawableLeft on Android button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try this:

```
int imgResource = R.drawable.left_img;
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imgResource, 0, 0, 0);
```

[Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)

Answer (score 12):

The safest way to set the left drawable without changing the values of the other drawables (top, right, and bottom):

```
Drawable[] drawables = textViewExample.getCompoundDrawables();
textViewExample.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(leftDrawable, drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you can use the

**setCompoundDrawables(...);**

method. Be aware that comes with **TextView**, not Button.

This is how to use it:

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.yourimage);
img.setBounds( 0, 0, 60, 60 );  // set the image size
txtVw.setCompoundDrawables( img, null, null, null );
```

Taken from: [How to programmatically set drawableLeft on Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)

Comment: How to set image in Rightside of the textview

Answer (score 0):

I recomend that instead of using a button you use an Imageview and add an onclick listener to it. That way you can just do `Imageview.setbitmap(bitmap)` and create a bitmap from one of your drawables

Answer (score 0):

just follow this code i hope it's really helpful for you..

```
boolean isIconChange;
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        isIconChange = !isIconChange;
        if(isIconChange){
           button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.like, 0, 0, 0);
           button.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        } else {
           button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.dislike, 0, 0, 0);
           button.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }
    }
});
```