# How to combine textview and imageview into image compound when imageview has width and height values in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

Hi have this in my XML file:

```
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/picture_text"
                android:layout_width="32dp" 
                android:layout_height="32dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/text"/>

            <TextView 
               android:id="@+id/textview_message"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
               android:text="@string/tap_message"
               android:onClick="GoToMessage"                
               android:clickable="true"
               style="@style/text_link"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Android lint complains with a warning that this should be combined in a textview compound. I can do that, but I don't understand how to set the width, height, and margin for the imageview...

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button/4502650#4502650 - Same can be sone with `TextView`

Answer (score 1):

It's recommending to add a drawable within the textview as follows:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/title"
     android:drawableLeft="@yourDrawable"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="yourText">
            </TextView>
```

Hope this helps.

Regards!

Comment: but then how do I change the width, height and margin of the drawable?

Comment: If you want to modify it the most common way is programatically create and format your drawable asset and then use the metho setCompoundDrawables() on TextView, that will do the trick...

Comment: You can use, setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()