# Set drawableImage from start even if the width is match_parent

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

In my app i am using a radio button.The radio button may contain text or images.
I am setting the width of radio button to match_parent.For texts it works fine but for images, the images are going to the end. I am setting the images programatically using setIntrinsicBound().I want the image to appear from start.

Code

```
rbOption1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, imageOpt1, 0);
```

Xml

```
            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rb_option1"
                style="@style/text_view_style"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"       
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:checked="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
```

Comment: share the screen shot of radiobutton with image ...

Answer (score 0):

You should set the image using below code
rbOption1.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imageOpt1,0,0,0);

You can refer this for more info [How to programmatically set drawableLeft on Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)

Comment: In your code you have set the resource id as 3rd parameter. It should be first parameter. Check your posted code.