# How To Change The Bitmap Resource On TouchEvent

Tags: java, android, bitmap, resources, surfaceview

This Should be easy and simple right?!
So, i have a `Gameobject` as a Button i reference it on a `GamePanel` that extents `SurfaceView` like this :

```
bby = new Buttons(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.babybutton),123 ,114 ,1);
```

`bby` is drawn and work fine,
my problem is How can i change the Resource (R.drawble.babybutton) to a different resource for e.g (R.drawble.babybutton2) on Touch?

just like pressing buttons animations!
Thanks in advance
(If my question look stupid please don't dislike! i'm very new to this).

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow!, drawable should be change on touch the surfaceview. right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a Drawable to a Bitmap?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Comment: @DevendraSingh yes! but it's not changing

Comment: Can you mail me whats problem exactly? droidwithme@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to change the button's drawable on touch on the surfaceview. than you can override this method in your surfaceview class.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //here you can set an another drawable to your button or can do something else
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

In your activity set a touchListener on the surfaceview.
after initialize the `surfaceView`. pass this `surfaceview` to the

```
surfaceView.setOnTouchListener(surfaceView)
```

Comment: okay good, but how can i set another drawble to my Button? that's what i need

Comment: Check [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood you, but if you want to change the button's rescource, this is how you should do it:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: No! it's not a Button, it's a Bitmap