# Change Button Image drawableLeft programmatically can not work in android

Tags: android, android-layout, button, android-drawable, android-resources

first I am telling you about the `Layout` for my Page. My `Button` is inside the `LinearLayout`. and I am using `weightSum` so that my `Button` `layout_height = "0dp"`.

Now this is my `Button` property.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton_shape_round"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:background="@color/button_background"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/round"
    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
    android:paddingRight="8dp"
     />
```

In that I have set `Image` to the `Button` which name is `round`.Now I want to set `OnclickListener` and Change it's `BackGroundColor` as well as `Image`.

```
 Button imagebutton_shape_round = (Button) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton_shape_round);
           imagebutton_shape_round.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                     imagebutton_shape_round.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_round, getApplicationContext().getTheme()), null, null, null);
                    }
                 else {
                    imagebutton_shape_round.setCompoundDrawables(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_round), null, null, null);
                    }

              imagebutton_shape_round.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(InventoryActivity.this,R.color.linearlayout_background));
                }
            });
```

as you can see we can set `drawableLeft` using this code.

```
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
txtVw.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( img, null, null, null);
```

[How to programmatically set drawableLeft on Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)

But my code `else` part why `getDrawable` is display `deprecated`.

I see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041027/android-getresources-getdrawable-deprecated-api-22)

that why I am using this in `If condition` `getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_round, getApplicationContext().getTheme()), null, null, null))`

but else part not work

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_round), null, null, null);
```

## Update :

Instead of Using this

```
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.white_round, getApplicationContext().getTheme())
```

I use this so it remove the `If else` condition

```
ContextCompat.getDrawable(InventoryActivity.this,R.drawable.white_round)
```

## Now Only One Problem is there

when I click the second `Image` is not display means when i click the `Image` is not change.

Answer (score 1):

When an API is deprecated and the new API that takes its place is most probably always compatible with older devices too, So you don't need to put any condition for Build Version.

I think you should try replace your `onClick` code snippet with this one and see if it works

```
Drawable image = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(R.drawable.white_round);
int h = image.getIntrinsicHeight();
int w = image.getIntrinsicWidth();
image.setBounds( 0, 0, w, h );
imagebutton_shape_round.setCompoundDrawables(image, null, null, null);
imagebutton_shape_round.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(InventoryActivity.this,R.color.linearlayout_background));
```

Comment: when I remove the `if else` it directly say that `Call require API 21 current min is 15 `. so that this will not work.