# Android adding image to button

Tags: java, android, image, button

I am trying to add an image to a button(image button or normal button) but not in a specific res/drawable folder. 
I want this image as a ImageView object or drawable object etc,  but I couldn't.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understood your question clearly. Could you explain it again please.

Comment: ok thanks. Here is what I want to do. I have a button and I want to put image object on it. For example in java language, there is setIcon() method and you can put icon object but in android there is not.

Answer (score 6):

You can set an icon for Button by adding following attribute in XML for Button like this:

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/button_icon"
```

If you want to know how to do it programmatically, follow this article:
[How to programmatically set drawableLeft on Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)

Or just add 'background':

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/qrcode"/>
```

But i think it's better if you use ImageButton, see this example:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/searchImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/your_image_drawable" />
```

Comment: For the ImageButton, if you want the image to fill a button of a given size you can also set the size of the button and then use android:scaleType="fitXY" to fill it. Adding some padding allows it not quite fill to the edge also.

Answer (score -1):

Use `ImageButton` and add `src` in your background:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@android:drawable/yourImageNameHere"
```

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88541/how-to-write-code-in-a-question-or-answer READ THIS TO WRITE YOUR FIRST QUESTION

Comment: just use src as "@drawable/yourimagename"