# Android: Is it possible to make a drawable left start from the left edge of a button?

Tags: android-layout, android-drawable, android-button

I've searched for weeks but there's no answer for this yet. Most suggestions are to use drawablepadding:left, but this only increases the space away from the egde of the button.

I've also tried drawablemargin:left and right, but they don't bring the button closer to the edge.

Here's the button I have;
[button with drawable left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LW6zG.png)

Here's what I hope to achieve:
[button with drawable close to edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcyeP.png)

here's the xml snippet:

```html
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back_button_white"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/negative_button"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Exit"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a compound drawable

[How to programmatically set drawableLeft on Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)

Answer (score 0):

try this, i hope is working

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/back_button_white"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/negative_button"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="Exit"
        tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        />
```

see this http://prntscr.com/cmvhzg, 
and please use `back_button_white` as trim image.