# Change Button Drawable Programmatically

Tags: android, button, drawable

I have a button with drawable left:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/post_feeling_btn"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/feeling_btn"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:text="Sentimento"/>
```

In my on resume method, I change the button's text programmatically:

```
Button setFeeling;
FeelingButton selectedFeeling;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    selectedFeeling = ((FeedActivity)getActivity()).getSelectedFeeling();
    if(selectedFeeling != null){
        setFeeling.setText(selectedFeeling.getFeeling());
    }
}
```

Is there a way to change my drawable left and set the image in the same method, using the image I have in my selectedFeeling object? I'm looking for something like:

```
setFeeling.setDrawable();
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

try something like this: for `drawableLeft`

```
int imgResource = R.drawable.your_drawable;
setFeeling.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(imgResource, 0, 0, 0);
setFeeling.setCompoundDrawablePadding(8);     //for padding
```

Thanks to the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)  Here also.

Comment: It worked out but the image is too large. Is there a way to set height and width?

Comment: @rob as I know, you can't set size of drawable left, try to reduce the size of image.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there:  [setBackgroundResource](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource(int))

```
setFeeling.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.appIcon);
```