# Drawable right position not proper

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have added drawable left and right programmatically but drawable right icon not in right.

[image]

What I did :

```
ReusableClass.setVectorDrawable(LoginActivity.this, R.drawable.ic_language_black_24dp, R.drawable.ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp, inputLanguage, R.color.colorAccent);

public static void setVectorDrawable(Context context, int leftIcon, int rightIcon, EditText editText, int color) {
    editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds((leftIcon != 0) ? getColouredIcon(context, leftIcon, color) : null,
            null,
            null,
            (rightIcon != 0) ? getColouredIcon(context, rightIcon, color) : null);
}

public static Drawable getColouredIcon(Context context, int icon, int color) {
    Drawable drawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), icon, null);
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable);
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, color);
    return drawable;
}
```

XML LOOKS LIKE THIS:

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_language"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/edittext_width"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:background="@color/bg_edittext"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:hint="@string/hint_language"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textColorHint="@color/input_text_hint_bg" />
```

Comment: can you share your xml file code

Comment: mybe it helps you   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programmatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button

Answer (score 0):

Check the document [SetCompundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).
You set your drawable in **bottom position**. 
Change your code to put your drawable to **right position**:

```
editText.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds((leftIcon != 0) ? getColouredIcon(context, leftIcon, color) : null,
        null,
        (rightIcon != 0) ? getColouredIcon(context, rightIcon, color) : null),
        null;
```