# Setting attributes of android checkboxes programmatically in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my application Im creating 10 checkboxes during runtime and I want to set the following xml attributes programmatically. I've been searching everywhere and cannot find any solution and I'm pretty new to android development. Would appreciate any kind of help!

```py
android:button="@null"
android:drawableTop="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

I've been researching on how to access the android:attr file without any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setButtonDrawable` to assign `android:button="@null"`

```
CheckBox checkBox = findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setButtonDrawable(null);
```

You can the `setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds()` method to assign the drawable. Use this code to get the value of `?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple`:

```
TypedValue typeValue = new TypedValue();
 getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple,typeValue, true);
checkBox.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0,typeValue.resourceId,0,0);
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

for drawable

```
setButtonDrawable(Drawable d)
```

for button

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I can't access the attrs.xml in my code and I have no idea how to. It looks like this right now:

checkbox.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,android.R.attr.listChoiceIndicatorMultiple,0,0);

Which doesn't work

Comment: you need to retrieve drawable and you need context for that try to use something like this 
Drawable img = getContext().getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.smiley );
checkbox.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds( null, img, null, null);

from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programmatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button