# How to add an Icon to a Button in Android from Java?

Tags: java, android, button, icons, android-button

I want to add an icon to a Button that I created from Java, after hours I didn't find a solution yet...

I have something like this:

```
Button button = new Button(context);
```

And I'd like to have something like this:

```
button.setIcon(Icon myicon);
```

Is this possible? ;)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to programmatically set drawableLeft on Android button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502605/how-to-programmatically-set-drawableleft-on-android-button)

Comment: Yes maybe, i'll try it! thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `MaterialButton`:

```
MaterialButton button = new MaterialButton(this);
button.setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_add_24px));
button.setText("Button");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! That's exactly what I was searching for! In fact I'm new to Android Studio and java, so I don't know all those classes of widgets yet... I should learn them ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a Button with image then in XML you have ImageButton that have attribute of drawableLeft/drawableRight..etc.
So you can set in from there. In java I think you can set in the same way by calling setResourceDrawable.

Answer (score 0):

you could also `setIcon` an XML file, Please try this

```
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click Me"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_icon" <!--also have drawableLeft:-->
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```