# Only change left drawable in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there a way of only changing the left drawable in kotlin using code?
In my case I have a speedmode selector from 1 to 8 and when a car(s) is selected you then press a speedmode and the icon changes in the button of the car. I have this but it removes the right drawable.

```
 for (speedModeSelecter in speedList)
    {
        speedModeSelecter.setOnClickListener{
            for(kartBox in kartList)
            {
                if(kartBox.isChecked) {
                   kartBox.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.mipmap.ic_speedmode1, 0 ,0 ,0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[a picture of what it should look like here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYR3T.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44925111/608312

Comment: That is in java not kotlin

Comment: Just FYI for the future, you can paste Java code into Android Studio and it'll autoconvert to Kotlin. Java solutions will usually work for Kotlin.

Comment: Yeah I noticed :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Kotlin**

```
var leftDrawable: Drawable =
    getContext()
        .getResources()
        .getDrawable(R.drawable.yourdrawable)

var drawables: Array<Drawable> = button.compoundDrawables

//setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(leftDrawable, drawables[1], drawables[2], drawables[3])
```